# How to add dynamic input fields into an array in Ionic 4?

Tags: html, arrays, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a requirement to add a field dynamically in my Ionic 4 app. I have declared an array variable in my ts file.

```
fields: [];
```

When I press the button I want to generate a new field with inputs fields. This is my code on the view:

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let field of fields">
      <ion-col>
        <ion-input></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-input></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

This is my code for the button:

```
 <ion-button expand="full" (click)="addField()">Add field</ion-button>
```

How can I add a row dynamically when I press the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plunker that gives an example of how this is possible: https://embed.plnkr.co/6YPQXH/

Basically you have an array of values for the input values:

```
 words2 = [{value: 'word1'}, {value: 'word2'}, {value: 'word3'}, {value: ''}];
```

and you add to it in your method addField()

You can iterate through adding accessing the values with the index as such:

```
<div *ngFor="let word2 of words2; in as index" class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="words2[in].value" name="name{{in}}" class="form-control" #name="ngModel" required />
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
```

Comment: This is the style of HTML do you have the Ionic 4 version for this?

Comment: NgFor is from the same module; you can use ion-input if needed in place of input

Comment: I gonna test it I will let you know!